# What layer vswitches are in VMware workstation?

Tags: networking, virtualization, switch

On what layer vmware workstation vswitches work, how can i manage vswitches just like physical switch?

Comment: To manage vswitches, You will need a **`Virtual Infrastructure client`**. I am not sure , but I think in case of vmware, it's `vSphere Client`

Answer (score 1):

As Not much details are provided in the question, The answer is subjected to improvements and edits.

---

> On what layer vmware workstation vswitches work ?

Going by official Documentations :

- [Virtual Networking Information Guide](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/virtual_networking_concepts.pdf) (See under `How Virtual Ethernet Adapter work`)
- And [Article : Choosing Network adapter](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1001805)

It is clear that `vswitches` can have one of [these 5](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1001805) as the `Virtual Ethernet Adapter` :

- vmxnet | vmxnet2 | vmxnet3
- vlance
- e1000 | e1000e
- vswif
- vmknic

And, stated in the document under section `How Virtual Ethernet Adapter work` is this :

> All five of the virtual network devices share the following characteristics:
>
> •  They have their own MAC addresses and unicast/multicast/
>   broadcast filters.
>
> •  They are strictly Layer 2 Ethernet adapter devices

So, It says **`strictly Layer 2`** Ethernet adapter devices

---

> how can i manage vswitches just like physical switch ?

As I already commented upon it, You will need a Virtual Infrastructure client. I am not sure , but I think for vmware, it is **`vSphere Client`**

Feel free to add-in more details.